# Css click sub menu bold main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When i clicked sub menu, i would like main menu highlight background.

My coding as the following:

```
<div id="dmenubg">
    <ul id="nav" class="drop">
     <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="aaa.php">AAA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
        $(".drop li a").each(function() {
            //alert(str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()));
            if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
                $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
            }
        });
        $(".drop li ul a").each(function() {
                if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                $(".drop.li.ul.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
                $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
            }
        });
     })
</script>


Result of my menu:

Home      **Service**
          **AAA**
          BBB
          CCC
```

When click on AAA Item, I want to highlight Services and AAA.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see any click event in your code. How click works in your code?

Comment: Dear can you edit my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your javascript a bit.  The basic idea is now we look through every anchor for a match then check to see if it has a valid menu parent to match.

Note that if you want just the text for the parent to be highlighted then you need to do outerNav.find(">a").addClass().

```
$(".drop li a").each(function() {

  if (str.indexOf($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
       $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
       $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
       var outerNav = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
       if(outerNav.is("li")) {
          /* Use this code to highlight the entire ul contents */
          //outerNav.addClass("highlight");
          /* Use this code to highlight just the parent li a */
          outerNav.find(">a").addClass("highlight");
       }
  }
});
```

Comment: if i want to highlight background.

Comment: Here's an example of it working with a background http://jsfiddle.net/2TwMt/1/ .  Have you added the necessary .highlight code to your css?  You can simulate page changes by changing the str variable and running it again.

Answer (score 0):

$(".drop > li > a") as Selector Than it will hightlight only First Level of Menu.
Not all  anchor link under .drop li.

I hope this will solve your issue